# Japanese Multiplication figure using Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

Japanese has invented unique multiplication style using dot and lines. Here is the depiction of their style.

[image]

I want to draw the figure from scratch using `tikz` of else. I have zero idea where to start drawing it. Any altruist can help me out there?

Note: The curve lines are not rigid, they must be smooth and flexible and creative as you imagine. There should be numbers under curves in each group like a label or count of dots.

Basic template:

```
\documentclass[statementpaper,11pt,twoside]{memoir}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit,positioning,hobby}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        % figure
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Image credit: [1.](https://www.wikihow.com/Multiply-Using-the-Line-Method) [2.](https://interestingengineering.com/tiktoker-shows-unorthodox-method-of-japanese-multiplication)

Comment: Should it be scalable (even parametric) or just this example?

Comment: @mais It should be scalable (parametric, if possible) so that I have a control to change it accordingly.

Comment: Why the question got a Down vote `-1`? Anything wrong with it?

Comment: +1 (making it 0 again)

Comment: I didn't downvote although the question is a do-it-for-me. I'm asking myself what kind of advantage has this “Japanese multiplication” whose only merit (if any) is to avoid learning the multiplication table and that's pretty inefficient when the figures are large. It's *exactly* the standard tabular multiplication, just a bit fancier.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Something to start with (did I even get it right?):

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=5mm]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{hobby}

\newcommand{\japanesemultiplication}[2]{%

    \def\splitfirst##1##2\relax{
        \def\firsttens{##1}
        \def\firstones{##2}
    }
    \def\splitsecnd##1##2\relax{
        \def\secndtens{##1}
        \def\secndones{##2}
    }
    \splitfirst#1\relax
    \splitsecnd#2\relax
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{scope}[rotate=135]
            \foreach \x in {1,...,\firsttens} {
                \draw[blue] ({1+\x},-10) -- ({1+\x},10);
            }
            \foreach \x in {1,...,\firstones} {
                \draw[blue] ({-1-\x},-10) -- ({-1-\x},10);
            }
            \foreach \y in {1,...,\secndtens} {
                \draw[red] (-10,{1+\y}) -- (10,{1+\y});
            }
            \foreach \y in {1,...,\secndones} {
                \draw[red] (-10,{-1-\y}) -- (10,{-1-\y});
            }
            \foreach \x in {1,...,\firsttens} {
                \foreach \y in {1,...,\secndtens} {
                    \node[fill, circle] (a\x\y) at ({1+\x},{1+\y}) {};
                }
                \foreach \y in {1,...,\secndones} {
                    \node[fill, circle] (b\x\y) at ({1+\x},{-1-\y}) {};
                }
            }
            \foreach \x in {1,...,\firstones} {
                \foreach \y in {1,...,\secndtens} {
                    \node[fill, circle] (c\x\y) at ({-1-\x},{1+\y}) {};
                }
                \foreach \y in {1,...,\secndones} {
                    \node[fill, circle] (d\x\y) at ({-1-\x},{-1-\y}) {};
                }
            }
            \coordinate (max) at ({1.5+\firsttens},{-1.5-\secndones});
            \coordinate (maxr) at ({1+\firsttens},-1);
            \coordinate (maxl) at (1,{-1-\secndones});
            \coordinate (min) at ({-1.5-\firstones},{1.5+\secndtens});   
            \coordinate (minr) at (-1,{1+\secndtens});   
            \coordinate (minl) at ({-1-\firstones},1);
            \coordinate (null) at (-.5,-.5);
            \coordinate (nulr) at (.5,.5);
            
            \coordinate (onea) at (1,11);
            \coordinate (oneb) at (1,6);
            \coordinate (onec) at (1,1);
            \coordinate (oned) at (6,1);
            \coordinate (onee) at (11,1);
    
            \coordinate (twoa) at (-1,-11);
            \coordinate (twob) at (-1,-6);
            \coordinate (twoc) at (-1,-1);
            \coordinate (twod) at (-6,-1);
            \coordinate (twoe) at (-11,-1);
        \end{scope}
    
        \draw[thick, black] (max) to[closed, curve through={(maxl) .. (null) .. (minl) .. (min) .. (minr) .. (nulr) .. (maxr)}] cycle;
    
        \draw[thick, black] (onea) to[curve through={(oneb) .. (onec) .. (oned)}] (onee);
    
        \draw[thick, black] (twoa) to[curve through={(twob) .. (twoc) .. (twod)}] (twoe);
        
    \end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}

\japanesemultiplication{42}{21}

\japanesemultiplication{11}{11}

\japanesemultiplication{99}{99}

\end{document}
```

Results in the following (the last one is merely to show the most extreme example):

[image]

[image]

[image]

(Only numbers between 11 and 99 except numbers evenly divisible by 10 are allowed. But this is probably obvious.)

---

**Update**

I added the possibility to style everything via an optional argument of the macro. I also added the numbers that represent the sum of the intersection nodes.

If you want to place these pictures in your document, you could use `\resizebox{10cm}{!}{\japanesemultiplication{42}{21}}` for example to resize the width of the picture to 10cm.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{hobby}

\newcommand{\japanesemultiplication}[3][]{%

    \def\splitfirst##1##2\relax{
        \def\firsttens{##1}
        \def\firstones{##2}
    }
    \def\splitsecnd##1##2\relax{
        \def\secndtens{##1}
        \def\secndones{##2}
    }
    \splitfirst#2\relax
    \splitsecnd#3\relax
    
    \tikzset{
        canvas/.style={rotate=135},
        first number/.style={blue},
        second number/.style={red},
        crossing/.style={fill, circle},
        group/.style={thick, black},
        first group/.style={},
        second group/.style={},
        third group/.style={},
        digit/.style={font=\Huge},
        first digit/.style={left of=one},
        second digit/.style={below of=min},
        third digit/.style={right of=two},
    }

    \begin{tikzpicture}[#1]
        \begin{scope}[canvas]
            \foreach \x in {1,...,\firsttens} {
                \draw[first number] ({1+\x},-10) -- ({1+\x},10);
            }
            \foreach \x in {1,...,\firstones} {
                \draw[first number] ({-1-\x},-10) -- ({-1-\x},10);
            }
            \foreach \y in {1,...,\secndtens} {
                \draw[second number] (-10,{1+\y}) -- (10,{1+\y});
            }
            \foreach \y in {1,...,\secndones} {
                \draw[second number] (-10,{-1-\y}) -- (10,{-1-\y});
            }
            \foreach \x in {1,...,\firsttens} {
                \foreach \y in {1,...,\secndtens} {
                    \node[crossing] (a\x\y) at ({1+\x},{1+\y}) {};
                }
                \foreach \y in {1,...,\secndones} {
                    \node[crossing] (b\x\y) at ({1+\x},{-1-\y}) {};
                }
            }
            \foreach \x in {1,...,\firstones} {
                \foreach \y in {1,...,\secndtens} {
                    \node[crossing] (c\x\y) at ({-1-\x},{1+\y}) {};
                }
                \foreach \y in {1,...,\secndones} {
                    \node[crossing] (d\x\y) at ({-1-\x},{-1-\y}) {};
                }
            }
            \coordinate (max) at ({1.5+\firsttens},{-1.5-\secndones});
            \coordinate (maxr) at ({1+\firsttens},-1);
            \coordinate (maxl) at (1,{-1-\secndones});
            \coordinate (min) at ({-1.5-\firstones},{1.5+\secndtens});   
            \coordinate (minr) at (-1,{1+\secndtens});   
            \coordinate (minl) at ({-1-\firstones},1);
            \coordinate (null) at (-.5,-.5);
            \coordinate (nulr) at (.5,.5);
            
            \coordinate (one) at ({1+\firsttens},{1+\secndtens});
            \coordinate (onea) at (1,11);
            \coordinate (oneb) at (1,6);
            \coordinate (onec) at (1,1);
            \coordinate (oned) at (6,1);
            \coordinate (onee) at (11,1);
    
            \coordinate (two) at ({-1-\firstones},{-1-\secndones});
            \coordinate (twoa) at (-1,-11);
            \coordinate (twob) at (-1,-6);
            \coordinate (twoc) at (-1,-1);
            \coordinate (twod) at (-6,-1);
            \coordinate (twoe) at (-11,-1);
        \end{scope}
    
        \draw[group, second group] (max) to[closed, curve through={(maxl) .. (null) .. (minl) .. (min) .. (minr) .. (nulr) .. (maxr)}] cycle;
    
        \draw[group, first group] (onea) to[curve through={(oneb) .. (onec) .. (oned)}] (onee);
    
        \draw[group, third group] (twoa) to[curve through={(twob) .. (twoc) .. (twod)}] (twoe);
        
        \node[digit, first digit] {%
            \pgfmathparse{\firsttens*\secndtens}%
            \pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}%
        };
        
        \node[digit, second digit] {%
            \pgfmathparse{\firsttens*\secndones+\secndtens*\firstones}%
            \pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}%
        };

        \node[digit, third digit] {%
            \pgfmathparse{\firstones*\secndones}%
            \pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}%
        };

    \end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}

\resizebox{10cm}{!}{\japanesemultiplication{42}{21}}

\end{document}
```

`\japanesemultiplication{42}{21}` would now result in:

[image]

---

**Addendum**

In case you want to check for invalid input, you can add this snippet before the `\tikzset` part or at least before `\begin{tikzpicture}`. It will return an error message if either argument contains a string that is not made of exactly two numbers between 1 and 9:

```
% === invalid input handling === %
\newif\ifinvalid\invalidfalse
\ifnum0<\firsttens\else\invalidtrue\fi%
\ifnum0<\firstones\else\invalidtrue\fi%
\ifnum10>\firstones\else\invalidtrue\fi%
\ifnum0<\secndtens\else\invalidtrue\fi%
\ifnum0<\secndones\else\invalidtrue\fi%
\ifnum10>\secndones\else\invalidtrue\fi%
\ifinvalid
  \PackageError{japanesemultiplications}{Invalid input!}{Only numbers made of exactly two digits between 1 and 9 allowed.}
\fi
% === === %%
```

Comment: Sorry, something got mixed up. It should not be correct. =D Too many dots and curves ...

Comment: I think so. Moreover, I have to draw it in a document using `memoir` class. It is not scaled properly. Also, I should place the count numbers under each group.

Comment: This would make a neat little TikZ library!

Comment: @mmr I added the numbers. I also gave an example how to resize the pictures and how to place them inside a document.

Comment: @Crazymoomin It's good idea in deed. @`Jasper Habicht` may take a step to forward.

Comment: Haha, I can't stop testing for the craziest numbers, just to watch hobby draw its funny curves. When making it a library, it would be probably a good idea to test against invalid input, because the results are a bit unpredictable.

Comment: @JasperHabicht perhaps also a fallback for LaTeX 2e, I think `hobby` uses LaTeX 3, so another way to draw the curves using standard TikZ bezier.

Comment: @Crazymoomin the fact that `hobby` uses LaTeX3 functionality does not mean that a fallback is needed for LaTeX2e.  It compiles just fine with existing LaTeX compilers.

Comment: @AndrewStacey OK, the manual seemed to suggest otherwise. I assume there is a fallback within `hobby` itself, perhaps using `PGFmath`.

Comment: @Crazymoomin no fallback is needed.  LaTeX3 provides a convenient programming layer that is fully compatible with LaTeX2e.  Many packages use it, and you are likely to be using it without realising in your documents.  There are many q&as here that try to explain the relationship between 2e and 3, but it is not that 3 is designed to replace 2e in a traditional sense.

Comment: I made one last update fixing the macro names (this did not result in wrong output, I just gave them the wrong names) and adding an idea about how to test against invalid input.

Comment: @AndrewStacey Well, TIL! Forgive me for my ignorance, I've only written a package in 2e. Would've probably been easier had I known!

Comment: @Crazymoomin No forgiveness needed - it's not a normal paradigm.  And, I do find it much, much easier programming in L3 than L2e.

Comment: Simply spectacular

Comment: Vote for a new library 

Comment: I don't think that this code is really suitable for a library, since it essentially only just provides one single command.